# warning: format ‘%d’ expects a matching ‘int’ argument [-Wformat=]

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <time.h>  

int main()
{

    FILE *bp=NULL;
    bp = fopen("binary.txt","w");
    if(bp == NULL)
    printf("Error!\n");
    else
   // {

        srand(unsigned(time(NULL)));
        int M = RAND_MAX / 2;
        int N = 100000;
        int s[N], ss[N-1];
        for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
        {

             if(rand() > M)
             s[i] = 1;
             else
             s[i] = 0;


        }
       for(int i=0, j=0; i<N-1; i++)
       {
         if(!s[i])
         {
               if(s[i+1])
                 ss[j] = 1;
                 else
                ss[j] = 0;
                j++;


            }

            if(s[i])
          {
               if(!s[i+1])
                 ss[j] = 0;//-1;
                else
                 ss[j] = -1;//0;
                 j++;


           }
              if(s[i])
          {
               if(s[i+1])
                 ss[j] = -1;
                else
                 ss[j] = 0;
                 j++;


           }


           //fprintf(bp,"%d\t%d\t%d\n",s[i],s[i+1],ss[j-1]);
           fprintf(bp,"%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t\
           %d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t\
           %d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t\
           %d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\n",
           s[i],s[i+1],s[i+2],s[i+3],s[i+4],s[i+5],s[i+6],s[i+7],s[i+8],s[i+9],s[i+10],s[i+11],s[i+12],s[i+13],s[i+14],s[i+15],
           s[i+16],s[i+17],s[i+18],s[i+19],s[i+20],s[i+21],s[i+22],s[i+23],s[i+24],s[i+25],s[i+26],
           s[i+27],s[i+28],s[i+29],s[i+30,s[i+31],s[i+32],s[i+33],s[i+34],s[i+35]],s[i+36],s[i+37],
           s[i+38],s[i+39],s[i+40],s[i+41],s[i+42],s[i+43],s[i+44],s[i+45],s[i+46],s[i+47],s[i+48],
           s[i+49],s[i+50],s[i+51],s[i+52],s[i+53],s[i+54],s[i+55],s[i+56],s[i+57],s[i+58],s[i+59],
           s[i+60],s[i+61],s[i+62],s[i+63],s[i+64],s[i+65],s[i+66],s[i+67],s[i+68],s[i+69],s[i+70],
           s[i+71],s[i+72],s[i+73],s[i+74],s[i+75],s[i+76],s[i+77],s[i+78],s[i+79],s[i+80],s[i+81],
           s[i+82],s[i+83],s[i+84],s[i+85],s[i+86],s[i+87],s[i+88],s[i+89],s[i+90],s[i+91],s[i+92],
           s[i+93],s[i+94],s[i+95],s[i+96],s[i+97],s[i+98],s[i+99]);


         }

       return 0; 
   // }


   //  fclose(bp);
     //bp = NULL;

}
```

Error message:

```
binary3.c: In function ‘int main()’:
binary3.c:78:67: warning: format ‘%d’ expects a matching ‘int’ argument [-Wformat=]
            s[i+93],s[i+94],s[i+95],s[i+96],s[i+97],s[i+98],s[i+99]);
                                                                   ^
binary3.c:78:67: warning: format ‘%d’ expects a matching ‘int’ argument [-Wformat=]
binary3.c:78:67: warning: format ‘%d’ expects a matching ‘int’ argument [-Wformat=]
binary3.c:78:67: warning: format ‘%d’ expects a matching ‘int’ argument [-Wformat=]
binary3.c:78:67: warning: format ‘%d’ expects a matching ‘int’ argument [-Wformat=]
vanita@banhita:~/Desktop$
```

Comment: Did you have a question? Have you considered a loop?

Comment: Sorry, yes, I have given %d for all the data to be printed ,but still I am getting the error in formatting. I also tried to use for loop for fprintf. It takes more time for compiling and does not end at all. I would like to print the data row wise.

Comment: for(i=0;i<=100;i++)
           {
           
           fprintf(bp,"%d\t%d\t",s[i],s[i+1]...);
           
           }

Answer (score 3):

Your gruesome call to `fprintf()` includes:

```
s[i+27],s[i+28],s[i+29],s[i+30,s[i+31],s[i+32],s[i+33],s[i+34],s[i+35]],
                              ^                                       ^
```

Note the missing bracket above the first caret mark, and the extra one above the second caret mark (as [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45809483/warning-format-d-expects-a-matching-int-argument-wformat#comment78576730_45809591) by [Retired Ninja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/920069/retired-ninja)).  It shows up as inconsistent alignment when you look at the code.  I don't think you showed all the error messages, either.  Because of the bracketing, you've effectively not printed 5 values (`i+30`, `s[i+31]`, etc become expressions in a comma operator), and `s[i+35]` is used as the index into `s` for what should have been `s[i+30]`.

Note too that the use of `\` and newline doesn't eliminate white space, so your format string has a number of chunks of blanks in the middle of it.

You really need to reorganize.  Assuming you need the single function call, then consider:

```
fprintf(bp,
       "%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t"
       "%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t"
       "%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t"
       "%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t"
       "%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t"
       "%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t"
       "%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t"
       "%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t"
       "%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t"
       "%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\n",
       s[i+ 0], s[i+ 1], s[i+ 2], s[i+ 3], s[i+ 4], s[i+ 5], s[i+ 6], s[i+ 7], s[i+ 8], s[i+ 9],
       s[i+10], s[i+11], s[i+12], s[i+13], s[i+14], s[i+15], s[i+16], s[i+17], s[i+18], s[i+19],
       s[i+20], s[i+21], s[i+22], s[i+23], s[i+24], s[i+25], s[i+26], s[i+27], s[i+28], s[i+29],
       s[i+30], s[i+31], s[i+32], s[i+33], s[i+34], s[i+35], s[i+36], s[i+37], s[i+38], s[i+39],
       s[i+40], s[i+41], s[i+42], s[i+43], s[i+44], s[i+45], s[i+46], s[i+47], s[i+48], s[i+49],
       s[i+50], s[i+51], s[i+52], s[i+53], s[i+54], s[i+55], s[i+56], s[i+57], s[i+58], s[i+59],
       s[i+60], s[i+61], s[i+62], s[i+63], s[i+64], s[i+65], s[i+66], s[i+67], s[i+68], s[i+69],
       s[i+70], s[i+71], s[i+72], s[i+73], s[i+74], s[i+75], s[i+76], s[i+77], s[i+78], s[i+79],
       s[i+80], s[i+81], s[i+82], s[i+83], s[i+84], s[i+85], s[i+86], s[i+87], s[i+88], s[i+89],
       s[i+90], s[i+91], s[i+92], s[i+93], s[i+94], s[i+95], s[i+96], s[i+97], s[i+98], s[i+99]);
```

This is brutally systematic, but allows you to generate the code (I should have done that rather than messing around editing in Firefox), and more importantly it allows you to spot inconsistencies.  It uses string concatenation to create the format string.

I think you'd do better with a loop — ten calls printing 10 values per iteration, or even 100 calls printing 1 value per iteration.

```
for (int j = 0; j < 100; j += 10)
{
    fprintf(bp,
           "%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d%c",
           s[i + j + 0], s[i + j + 1], s[i + j + 2], s[i + j + 3], s[i + j + 4],
           s[i + j + 5], s[i + j + 6], s[i + j + 7], s[i + j + 8], s[i + j + 9],
           (j == 90) ? '\n' : '\t');
}
```

Or:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++)
{
    fprintf(bp, "%d%c", s[i + j], (j == 99) ? '\n' : '\t');
}
```

Given a choice, I'd probably use the last loop; it's by far the simplest to get right.

I trust that the data is not for human consumption.  One hundred tab separated values on a line makes for unpleasant reading — for humans.  Computers don't care.

<sup>*The code above has not been compiled.  There could be mistakes in it.*</sup>

Comment: I ran with g++.

Comment: `s[i+35]]` too.

Comment: I have shown all the errors and I ran the code with g++.

Comment: I should check these trivial mistakes carefully before asking a question.sorry

Comment: @Kevin, you understand `gcc` is the C compiler and `g++` is the C++ compiler -- Right?

Comment: yes, If I run the code with gcc it shows more errors,

Comment: thanks Jonathan. I am using for loop printing 100 data.